# 2. In a row mean of consecutive columns up to end

Tags: mean

I have a matrix  A=1×100. Now I want to find the mean of row for each consecutive five columns up to last. that is Answer=mean(1-5 columns), mean(6-10 columns), mean(11-15columns),…. mean(96-100 columns). As a result I want to get one row vector containing 20 columns. I tried as mean(A(1,1:5:100)) but not get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reshape` and `mean`:

```
mean(reshape(A, 5, 20), 1)
```

Comment: thanks.your code work well.In case of A=54×100 can we use the same code?

Comment: The code is similar but not the same. If my answer helps you, mark it as correct please